# How would I connect to a MySQL database back-end from an Android device's application?

Tags: java, android, mysql, javafx, apk

I have developed a standalone JavaFx application in Netbeans with a MySQL database back-end which I want to also package as an APK package for running on Android. How would I go about porting the MySQL database script it uses to Android?

Comment: I bet you won't succeed in porting MySQL to Android. Consider switching to client-service architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what do you mean my packaging a JavaFx App as an apk. 
Other than that, if you plan to use the mySQL in your Android app, simply replicate the MySQL schema to Android SQLite and work with it.

Comment: Forgive my English. Yeah that's what I want to do. I intend to use MySQL in my Android app. I have a central MySQL database where desktop users and Android devices users need to connect to so that they all connect to the same database.

Comment: What you are talking about is a business requirement - a use-case. As I understand, you want your different clients to get/put/post/delete and perform different operation on the MySQL data. Here is my suggestion to you -

Comment: 1- Expose set of Web Services to your client


2- Make these Web services stateless (JAX-RS specifications) so that different clients of yours (Desktop, Mobile App, Web App) can call it.


3- Make your Web Service connect to your MySQL DB in question

Comment: And please see the number of down votes your Question is getting. This not a programming question. Please be more specific with what you ask.

Comment: Exactly! I want users to do CRUD operations to a central MySQL from different platforms. If I understand you correctly, you saying that I need to come up with a web service that connects to MySQL that all my platforms can consume? I find that easier than trying to figure out how MySQL database can sit on an Android device.

Comment: I was wondering how from Android I would be able to connect to MySQL database back-end. Now I gather it is a feasible feat if I consume a stateless web service to MySQL centralized database.

Comment: Mark my answer to correct answer if you have found it helpful.

Comment: sure I will. You shed a more insightful approach onto the challenge I had. Your suggestion of stateless web services is one of the viable options I have at my disposal now. Thanks indeed.